# Android: how can I create an array of preferences with context?

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

At the moment I have some test code that starts something like this:

```
    CheckBoxPreference cb1 = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    CheckBoxPreference cb2 = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
```

What I want to achieve is an array of CheckBoxPreferences which I would expect to look something like this:

```
private CheckBoxPreference[] mFilterSubjects = new CheckBoxPreference(this)[24];
```

However, this generates an error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to CheckBoxPreference". The following code compiles correctly:

```
private CheckBoxPreference[] mFilterSubjects = new CheckBoxPreference[24];
```

However, if I try to do something with an element of the array, e.g. mFilterSubjects[0], I get a NullPointerException because there is no context.

How can I change my declaration to work properly, in other words, how do I declare each element of the array with context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just creating an empty array to hold 24 elements, that's why you get null pointer:

```
private CheckBoxPreference[] mFilterSubjects = new CheckBoxPreference[24];
```

you need to add preferences to that array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
    mFilterSubjects[i] = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such a prompt answer. That fixed the problem. It just seems weird having 'new' twice, though.